# find part of a word and then replace the whole word with a string

Tags: php, regex

so if i have the text:

"this is going to be really great"

and i have the needle "goi"

i want it to find *going* and then replace it with the link

```
<a href="http://wwww.something.com/going">going</a>
```

can you help me? i am really bad in regex

Answer (score 5):

You can use the following regex to match your partial needle plus the rest of the word around it:

```
$regex = '\b\w*' . $needle . '\w*\b';
```

then pass that to `preg_replace`:

```
$newtext = preg_replace($regex, '<a href="http://www.something.com/$0">$0</a>', $oldtext);
```

Comment: You should add the capturing group and then show how to use that to build the link ;)

Comment: Doesn't actually need a capturing group - the entire match is what you'd want to use anyways.

Comment: Yeah, well, you'd still need some replace code, which you added now ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "this is going to be really great";
$s = explode(" ", $str);
foreach ($s as $k=>$v)
{
    if (strpos($v,"goi") !== FALSE)
    {
        $s[$k]= '<a href="http://wwww.something.com/' . $v . '">' . $v . "</a>";
    }
}
print_r(implode(" ", $s));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/(\bgoi\w*)/', 
           '<a href="http://www.something.com/$1">$1</a>', $str)
```

`\b` is for word boundary - without this, it will match `going` in `ongoing`